# Sort column by date

Tags: sorting, libreoffice

I've got a sheet which looks like this:

```
01 Sep 2016 CR
02 Aug 2016 CR
02 Aug 2016 BP
02 Jul 2016 TFR
02 Jul 2016 DR
02 Jun 2016 CR
03 Mar 2016 CR
04 Jun 2016 TFR
06 Jan 2017 BP
07 Oct 2016 DD
08 Apr 2016 DR
08 Apr 2017 DR
```

Note: column 1 starts with `01 Sep 2016` and column 2 starts with `CR`.

However when I try and sort with `Sort > Sort Criteria > Sort Key > Column A` it has no effect on the order. I assume that's 'cos it's sorted on the first digit.

I've tried converting the column to Format > Date but it still stays the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't you need to decide on a date format even if you choose `Format > Date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough to view cells as date format.  The values must be converted to dates (stored as numbers) rather than strings.

To do this, select column A and go to *Data -> Text to Columns*.  In the dialog, select the column by clicking on the heading.  Then change the column type to `Date (DMY)` and press OK.

Now the values are stored as dates.  To show them as they originally looked, go to *Format -> Cells*.  Add a User-defined format code `DD MMM YYYY` and press OK.